# Rust multiple levels of indirections - Performance impact?

Tags: rust, reference, ownership

I've been experimenting with everyone's favorite new thing, rust. I'm coming from a C background, so I think this may be what is causing me issue here. I've tried to find a clear definitive answer online but could not. Here's my issue, simplified:

```rust
fn main() {
    let v : Vec<&str> = vec!["abc", "def"]; 
    let z : Vec<&&str> = v.iter().filter(|e| {e.starts_with("a")}).collect(); // type of `e` is &&&str!
    // do something with z
}
```

My issue occurs with the type of `z` and `e` (within the closure). I understand the need for the additional layer of reference for the ownership system. I also understand I can go around this issue using things liked `copied()` or `into_iter()` (for `z`'s type) or use `|&e|`.

However, I am wondering if there's a performance impact here. Even if I used `copied`, the type of `e` in `|e|` would still be a double reference. If pointers and references map 1:1, this seems like a waste. But references and pointers do not *need* (in this case at least) to map 1:1. The compiler could create a reference for the ownership rules, without deref a reference.

So here's my question: does multiple references translates 1:1 to pointers? Are there optimizations? In this case (`e` for example), am I going through two levels of indirection?

Comment: The `Vec<&&str>` is really an antipattern imo, I don't see a single reason for keeping a `&&` around for longer than absolutely necessary.

Comment: @Finomnis Convenience. I usually do this when I don't care.

Comment: But the knowledge that this will cause an actual double reference to be generated by the compiler just bothers my perfectionism so hard :D That and the fact that `z` will now depend on `v`, which it wouldn't otherwise.

Comment: @Finomnis this is a _very_ toy example. The more troublesome part for me is the seemingly unavoidable double indirection in the argument for the `find` closure

Comment: @SamuelYvon Don't worry about this one. That will all be inlined.

Answer (score 3):

> Does multiple references translates 1:1 to pointers?

Yes.

But the compiler can optimize them out, as usual. In the case of iterators, it usually does. When all stuff will be inlined, the compiler will be able to convert the iterator to a simple loop, so this is rarely a problem. If it is, you can always use `copied()`, or even switch to simple loops. This is part of Rust's zero-cost abstraction story.

Comment: Without going into the generated assembly, is there a way I could have figured that out by myself? Or confirm that the optimization took place?

Comment: @SamuelYvon I don't think.

Comment: @SamuelYvon But that's the case for most compiler optimizations, like vectoring and loop unrolling, which also happen for iterators, or even in C/C++. All in all, benchmarking should be the decisive factor, imo.

Comment: @Finomnis I agree in your comment w.r.t performance overall. I'm learning the language and I'm just wondering about the mechanics around multiple levels of indirection when using `iter` and related functions. I haven't encountered documentation w.r.t optimization of chains of iter operations, but I may have missed it. I"m just wondering where the knowledge of the optimization comes from

Comment: @SamuelYvon Not sure... performance optimization experience? How do you get that knowledge in C/C++?